# How to fix the size of a latex table without breaking the width of page?

Tags: tables, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem when the width of my table is bigger than width of the page, If I changed the size of table the lines will  break up the lines of my table.I used template of springer. This is my table:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table*}[htp]
%\scriptsize        
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\begin{tabular}  {  |p{0.04\textwidth}|
p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 


%%{  |p{0.04\textwidth}|
%%p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 



\hline
Text Text Text
&

Text Text Text
&
Text Text Text
& 
Text  
& 
Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  

\\ \hline

{\multirow {10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Text Text } }}}  & 


%[origin=c] [3em]{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}


%{\multirow {2}[3em]{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}}  & 

{\multirow [c]{14}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ Text   }}}


 & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text .
& 

%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}

 
\begin{tabitemize}

\item
RSS. 
\item Text Text .

\item Text Text .
\end{tabitemize}
 & 
 
 

%\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text Text .
\item Text Text  .  
\item Text Text  %\hspace{0.28cm}
rate.
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}  

&   

Text Text Text   Text Text  Text Text .

& 
Text    Text Text  Text Text .

& 

Text 



\\ \cline{3-9}&  & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text  Text  Text  (10 Text   Text  5 Text ).
& 
 
 
 
 %\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text .
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text .
 
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}

& 

Text  Text   Text   Text .
&
Text  Text   Text   Text    Text  Text .
& 
Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text   Text .

& 

Text  \\ 


\cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 

\multirow{4}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text   }}  &  
&
Text -Text . 
 &
Text  Text   Text .
& 


Text  Text   Text   Text  in $t_{n}$.
& 

Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text  $t_{n+1}$.
& 
Text  Text  Text   Text  Text  Text   Text  Text .
& 
%\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
//
%} 
& 

Text  

\\ 
\hline

%\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 3}}

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text    }} & 

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text  }}
& 
Text Text . 
&
Text Text Text .
& 
%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
 
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}
&
Text  Text  Text   (Text , Text ,  Text , Text Text Text ).
& 
Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text Text Text .

& 


Text 

\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Text Text Text Text }
\label{Text }   
\end{table*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How or where is the `tabitemize` environment defined?

Comment: What exactly does "If I changed the size of table the lines will break up the lines of my table."  mean?

Comment: In your column width calculation you did not take into account the tabcolsep around each column. This is why your table ends up being wider than the textwidth.

Comment: This question seems to be quite identical to [How to fix the width of a tabular column by using weights in latex and active the auto-break lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550359/134144)

Comment: Could it be possible that you have two accounts here? (BraTaDor and Brm-Corvißio) If so, the Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).