# How to fix the width of a tabular column by using weights in latex and active the auto-break lines?

Tags: tables, width, cell, textwidth

I have created a table. I used template of `springer`. I want to fix the width of my table by using the `weights` option, but I don't know how to do that. I used `textwidth` but no positive results.

This is my code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table*}[htp]
%\scriptsize        
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\begin{tabular}  {  |p{0.04\textwidth}|
p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 


%%{  |p{0.04\textwidth}|
%%p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 



\hline
Text Text Text
&

Text Text Text
&
Text Text Text
& 
Text  
& 
Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  

\\ \hline

{\multirow {10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Text Text } }}}  & 


%[origin=c] [3em]{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}


%{\multirow {2}[3em]{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}}  & 

{\multirow [c]{14}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ Text   }}}


 & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text .
& 

%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}

 
\begin{tabitemize}

\item
RSS. 
\item Text Text .

\item Text Text .
\end{tabitemize}
 & 
 
 

%\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text Text .
\item Text Text  .  
\item Text Text  %\hspace{0.28cm}
rate.
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}  

&   

Text Text Text   Text Text  Text Text .

& 
Text    Text Text  Text Text .

& 

Text 



\\ \cline{3-9}&  & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text  Text  Text  (10 Text   Text  5 Text ).
& 
 
 
 
 %\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text .
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text .
 
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}

& 

Text  Text   Text   Text .
&
Text  Text   Text   Text    Text  Text .
& 
Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text   Text .

& 

Text  \\ 


\cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 

\multirow{4}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text   }}  &  
&
Text -Text . 
 &
Text  Text   Text .
& 


Text  Text   Text   Text  in $t_{n}$.
& 

Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text  $t_{n+1}$.
& 
Text  Text  Text   Text  Text  Text   Text  Text .
& 
%\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
//
%} 
& 

Text  

\\ 
\hline

%\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 3}}

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text    }} & 

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text  }}
& 
Text Text . 
&
Text Text Text .
& 
%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
 
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Text Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
 
\end{tabitemize}
%\end{tabular}
&
Text  Text  Text   (Text , Text ,  Text , Text Text Text ).
& 
Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text Text Text .

& 


Text 

\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Text Text Text Text }
\label{Text }   
\end{table*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is the table, I don't know why the width of table is bigger than the width of the page.

[image]

Comment: Because the sum of all the columns, all the space between columns and vertical rules is more than the text width.

Comment: @Sveinung How can I know the width of the textwidth ?

Comment: You have to reduce the width of the tabular, reduce font, tabcolsep etc. I had an example, but it did not work, give me a minute or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your document example is not complete. It not contain definition for `tabitemize` environment.
- For table environment the `tabularx` is used. For it is prescribed table width (to be equal to `\textwidth} and defined` X`column tape (modified to`L` which align cells' text to the left)
- List in cells are defined by use of the `enumitem` package and remamed to `tabitem` (if you prefer, you can change name to `tabitemize`).
- For more vertical space above/below cells' contents are used `\makegapedcells` macro defined in the `makecell` package
- For the first and the last horizontal line are used `Xhline{<width>}` defined in the `makecell` package for emphasize these lines
- From MWE (Minimal Working Example) are removed all commented lines, code is formated that is more compact and easy to read/maintain.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % new
\usepackage{enumitem}                               % new
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, 
                  after=\end{minipage}                   
                  }

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ 
        *{2}{|p{0.04\textwidth}}
        *{6}{|L}
            |p{0.04\textwidth}|}
    \Xhline{1pt}
Text Text Text
    &   Text Text Text
        &   Text Text Text
            &   Text
                &   Text Text  
                    & Text Text  
                        & Text Text  
                            & Text Text  
                                & Text Text     \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{7}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text Text}}  
    &   \multirow{10}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{Text}}
        &   Text Text Text
            &   Text Text
                &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item   RSS.
                \item Text Text 
                \item Text Text 
                    \end{tabitem}
                    &   \begin{tabitem}
                    \item Text Text 
                    \item Text Text 
                    \item Text Text rate.
                        \end{tabitem}
                        &   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                            &   Text Text Text Text Text
                                &   Text    \\ 
    \cline{3-9}
    &   &   Text Text Text 
            &   Text Text Text (10 Text Text 5 Text).
                &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item Text
                \item Text Text
                \item Text
                    \end{tabitem}
                    &   Text Text Text Text
                        &   Text Text Text Text Text Text
                            &   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
                                &   Text  \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-9}
\multirow{3}{=}{\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}}  
    &   &   Text -Text
            &   Text Text Text
                &   Text Text Text Text in $t_{n}$.
                    &   Text Text Text Text Text Text $t_{n+1}$.
                        &   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
                            &   &   Text    \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{=}{\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} 
    &   \multirow{6}{=}{\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}}
        &   Text Text
            &   Text Text Text
                &   \begin{tabitem}
                \item Text Text .
                \item Text .
                \item Text .
                \item Text .
                \item Text Text .
                \item Text Text .
                    \end{tabitem}
                    &   Text Text Text (Text, Text, Text, Text Text Text).
                        &   Text Text Text
                            &   Text Text Text Text
                                &   Text    \\ 
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Text Text Text Text }
\label{Text }
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

Comment: I don't understand what you modified

Comment: @Brm-Covißio, hm, all is explained in answer: let me repeat: (i) for table is used `tabularx` by which is prescribed width of table (see code), defined are list `tabitem` (which is missing in your MWE), added are vertical spaces above and below cells' contents by use the `\makegapedcells` macro (which is not mentioned in explanation, now added) and clean-up is your code.

Comment: I wont use tabularx, and I can't run the code

Comment: @Brm-Covißio, sorry but then my answer cant' help you. You then can stick with another answer (which not use `tabularx` package). However, there is not any reason why you should not use standard LaTeX package. But it is all up to you.

Comment: When i run it, that message is shown : ' ! Undefined control sequence.\enit@enditemize ...x \else \ifnum \enit@resuming=\@ne \enit@setresumekeys ... \end{tabularx} '

Comment: @Brm-Covißio, with my MWE this cannot happen. Tested again and result of test is shown in the image in answer.  You probably change something in it or you have old installation of LaTeX. Try to upgrade it to recent version.

Comment: I used Texmaker, the code don't work, please help me.

Comment: @Brm-Covißiom TeXmaker is only editor. My code is independent from editor and from LaTeX distribution. However, LaTeX should not to be to old. SO please, upgrade your LaTeX distribution (MikTeX? TeXLive?). Also you can try to test it on Overleaf on-line service (https://www.overleaf.com/l). Compiling there MWE works fine.

Comment: @Brm-Covißio The code in the answer works: if the code in your document doesn't work you have an error in code you have not shown. The error you show isn't really related to tabularx it is an error in an enumitem customisation of itemize

Comment: @Zarko you are a legend thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MWE, I use `tabular*` `\textwidth` wide. I reduced `\tabcolsep` and the fontsize. In addition, the command `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` ensure the tabular uses all available space. The new column (`N`) set the content ragged right. In addition, I increased the size of the last column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}          % twocolumn
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx, array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{table*}[htp]
 \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}  {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|N{04}|
N{04}|N{12}|N{12}|N{13}|N{13}|N{12}|N{12}|N{04}|} 

\hline
Text Text Text
&

Text Text Text
&
Text Text Text
& 
Text  
& 
Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  & Text Text  

\\ \hline

{\multirow {10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Text Text } }}}  & 


{\multirow [c]{14}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ Text   }}}

 & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text .
& 


\begin{itemize}

\item
RSS. 
\item Text Text .

\item Text Text .
\end{itemize}
 & 
 
\begin{itemize}
\item Text Text .
\item Text Text  .  
\item Text Text  
rate.
\end{itemize}

&   
Text Text Text   Text Text  Text Text .
& 
Text    Text Text  Text Text .
& 
Text 

\\ \cline{3-9}&  & 

Text Text Text .
& 
Text  Text  Text  (10 Text   Text  5 Text ).
& 
 
 \begin{itemize}
\item Text .
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text .
 
\end{itemize}
& 
Text  Text   Text   Text .
&
Text  Text   Text   Text    Text  Text .
& 
Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text   Text .
& 
Text  \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 
\multirow{4}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text   }}  &  
&
Text -Text . 
&
Text  Text   Text .
& 
Text  Text   Text   Text  in $t_{n}$.
& 
Text  Text   Text  Text   Text  Text  $t_{n+1}$.
& 
Text  Text  Text   Text  Text  Text   Text  Text .
& 
& 
Text  

\\ \hline

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text    }} & 

\multirow{8}{*} {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {   Text  }}
& 
Text Text . 
&
Text Text Text .
& 
 
\begin{itemize}
\item Text Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
\item Text  Text . 
 
\end{itemize}
&
Text  Text  Text   (Text , Text ,  Text , Text Text Text ).
& 
Text Text Text .
& 
Text Text Text Text .
& 
Text 

\\ \hline

\end{tabular*}
\caption{Text Text Text Text }
\label{Text }   
\end{table*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```